# How to Save Push Notifications of parse by SharedPreferences

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification, sharedpreferences

I am sending push notifications from pasrse.com, i want to save the push notifications such that they can be seen later after the app is closed.

I am able to receive the notifications in a separate activity's textview, but if i go to another acticity the notifications dissappear.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button Notify;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Notify = (Button)findViewById(R.id.notify);


        Notify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayPush.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.parse.Data","String text");
                startActivity(intent);    

        }
    });
    }
```

DisplayPush.java

```
public class DisplayPush extends Activity {
String jsonData;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String Titletobeput = "title";
    public static final String Messagetobeput = "mess";

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(DisplayPush.this,MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
  //  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification);

    TextView notification_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView notification_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);


    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras !=null)
      if(extras.containsKey("com.parse.Data"))
         jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");


    //Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");

    try{
        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String Title = notification.getString("title");
        String Message = notification.getString("alert");


        notification_message.setText(Message);
        notification_title.setText(Title);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putString(Titletobeput, Title);
        editor.putString(Messagetobeput, Message);
        editor.commit();
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong with the notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
}
```

Notification.xml(whre the notifications are shown)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ActivityMain.xml(just a button to show notification button)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="hasan.parsereceiveandshow.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press the button to display notifications" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notify"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:text="See Notifications" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way by which i can display complete notification on the status bar/notification dialog automatically ? As long messages get truncated.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your using Latest version of Parse Library (**Parse 1.9.3**) This is what you need to do

You need to create a class i.e `PushNotificationBroadcastReceiver` that extends `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` and override `onReceive` like this:

```
    public class PushNotificationBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    /**
     * Everytime a Push notification message comes, It is received here.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param intent  contains pushed Json or Message
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            JSONObject notification;
            notification = new JSONObject(extras.getString(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.KEY_PUSH_DATA));
//  Save Json to Shared Preferences. Add your Own implementation here
            String title = notification.getString("title");
            String message = notification.getString("alert");

            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("title", title);
            editor.putString("message", message);
            editor.commit();
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error Parsing JSON", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns the Activity Class which you want to open when notification is tapped
     *
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     * @return Activity Class which you want to open
     */
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivity(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return SomeActivity.class;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called once user taps on a Push Notification
     *
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    }

}
```

Also don't forget to register a `PushNotificationBroadcastReceiver` in your manifest file like this

```
        <receiver
            android:name="com.package.PushNotificationBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And thats all, If you need to take things a little further then i suggest you look at [Parse Push Notification documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-receiving-pushes)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: m going to try it now

Comment: after putting your code,i am not able to recieve any notification, if i comment your receiver code from manifest, i am able to receive the notification, but it is not getting saved. FYI i am sending json from my parse account

Comment: which parse library are you on ? And did you register the reciever in manifest file ?

Comment: strange try to put my code in onPushReceive instead of onRecieve

Comment: Also did you change com.package.PushNotificationBroadcastReceiver to your package name+broadcast receiver class  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82567/discussion-between-penta-and-sheraz-ahmad-khilji).

Answer (score 1):

Save notification info in a `SharedPreference`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(<Name>, <Mode>);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(<KEY>, notification_title.getText().toString()).commit();
//Similarly, save other infos
```

Extract info in other activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(<Name>, <Mode>);
String title = prefs.getString(<KEY>, <DefaultValue>);
```

Comment: i am putting the snippet 1 in Displaypush.java and snippet 2 in Mainactivity. Is that right @Greengoblin

Comment: Yes. Just ensure you create `SharedPreferences` with same name and mode

Comment: nope, didnot work, see this link n tell me if i did correct http://pastebin.com/6ksp2gDV

Comment: It looks correct to me. Are you sure code at both places is getting executed? Can you please debug it and let me know what is `SharedPreferences` outputting in `MainActivity`?

Comment: it is showing file path of the backup file /data/data/hasan.parsereceiveandshow/shared_prefs/MyPrefs.xml.bak

Comment: And is it saving the same thing in DisplayPush?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82281/discussion-between-penta-and-green-goblin).

Answer (score 1):

I quote the part of the question **" i want to save the push notifications such that they can be seen later after the app is closed."**

I did this and it works perfectly as i want it to.

DisplayPush.java

```
public class DisplayPush extends Activity {
    String jsonData;
    Button save;
    TextView notification_title;
    TextView notification_message;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String Titletobeput = "title";
    public static final String Messagetobeput = "alert";

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(DisplayPush.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        //  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notification);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView notification_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
         TextView notification_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);


        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
            if (extras.containsKey("com.parse.Data"))
                jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");


        //Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");

        try {
            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            String Title = notification.getString("title");
            String Message = notification.getString("alert");


            notification_message.setText(Message);
            notification_title.setText(Title);


            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String n = notification_title.getText().toString();
            String e = notification_message.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(Titletobeput, n);
            editor.putString(Messagetobeput, e);
            editor.commit();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong with the notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void Get(View view) {
        notification_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        notification_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Titletobeput)) {
            notification_title.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Titletobeput, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Messagetobeput)) {
            notification_message.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Messagetobeput, ""));

        }
    }
}
```

From `notification.xml` just call `android:onClick="Get"` on the Save button.

Here is my working project, with this answer's code.
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/atvi2gee5bycq6k/ParseReceiveAndShow-master1.zip?dl=0

Moderators before deleting my answer please do look at the code/project.

Comment: Your code is not working. could you please tell me what is the exact JSON that you send as a push?